# Is it possible to install my own Firefox XPI extension without signing it through AMO or at least without sending it to anyone?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I was looking for an extension that would let me change all fonts on a page to one font of my choosing. I found one such extension, but it only has a built-in list of its own fonts, and doesn't allow to customize it. So I unzipped its XPI, found the font list, modified it and now I want to make this custom extension to work just for me. But it doesn't, because the new file hash doesn't match the old hash in the manifest.

It used to be possible to disable extension signing check previously, but now it is mandatory.

It seems that the only way to make it install is to upload it to AMO (addons.mozilla.org) and retrieve it after it's signed. But what if I don't want to do that?

- I don't want to have to sign an extension that I trust;
- Sending sensitive information to a public addon repository is not a pleasant thought (I don't want anyone to find out that I secretly like *Comic Sans*);
- What if I don't have internet connection? I mean yea it's a browser, but still imagine that scenario. Maybe I'm browsing local pages, or maybe the aliens have destroyed AMO. Or maybe my country blocked the entire domain;
- I don't care about dealing with potential conflicts of some metadata/icons/fonts from another developer or using copyrighted data. This is just for me, I'm not trying to steal anything or make money doing it.

What are my options to make the custom extension work without all that trouble?